# Generate a number random with interval time c#

Tags: c#

I have a matrix int with 10 numbers, and I want to generate numbers randomly every 3 seconds. For example when run program random show number 2, wait 3 seconds show 5, wait 3 seconds show 10.... but I don't know how to add interval to generate

```
int[] numbers = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
Random rnd = new Random();
rnd.Next(1, numbers.Length);
```

Answer (score 2):

use the Timer so you won't lock the thread

```
      void Main()
      {
    int[] numbers = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    Random rnd = new Random();

    System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
    t.Elapsed += (s,e)=>{
        Console.WriteLine(rnd.Next(1, numbers.Length));
    };
    t.Start();
    Console.ReadLine();
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use [`Thread.Sleep`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.sleep(v=vs.110).aspx) to achieve the delay:

```
int[] numbers = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
Random rnd = new Random();
while (true)
{
    rnd.Next(1, numbers.Length);
    Thread.Sleep(3000) // 3000ms = 3 seconds
}
```

Be advised however that this locks the thread completely until the interval has passed. This shouldn't be a problem in a simple single-threaded program, but if you're dealing with something more complex or any sort of UI, you should look into using a [timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) instead.

Comment: If this is on the UI thread it won't make for an ideal user experience.